# insert inject node msg.payload value into postgresql database

Tags: node-red

i am trying to insert queryParameters a:25 value(25) into postgresqlDB. i am using below insert query but not worked.

output of function node="queryParameters: object
a: "25" "

insert into mode_value(register_value) values($a);

Comment: i have tried query  in function     msg.queryParameters=msg.queryParameters || {};
msg.queryParameters.a = msg.payload;
return msg;node but the error is  "Error: msg.payload must be an array of queries.

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58762189/edit) link under the question to add detail rather than comments.